# Dynamic broadcasting

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I would like to dynamically broadcast multiplying of Tensors along the dynamic dimension, which is batch size. I could hardcode batch size, but then inference on batch size equal 1 is impossible.

```
img_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, 28, 28, 1), name='real_img')

random_part = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (None), name='random_part')
```

During training time I will feed each placeholder with the same size of the first dimension. I would like to have `result = random_part * img_placeholder` such that `result[0] = random_part[0] * img_placeholder[0]`.

Currently just multiplying ends with Tensor of size `BATCH_SIZE, 28, 28, BATCH_SIZE`.

If broadcasting won't work as I would like (because there is dynamic dimension size) is there any possibility to do it in other way?

Comment: but then inference on batch size equal 1 is impossible? could you explain?

Comment: [As posted here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#tensor-shapes) It is impossible to feed a graph with Tensor of incompatible shape. If the network is built explicitly for training on 64 images per batch then you can't feed batch with one image into it.

Comment: you may prefer to build a robust prototype with two placeholders for training and inference.  While building the graph for inference reuse the variables used for training.

Comment: its not clear whether you want to broadcast for multi-gpu or single gpu..

Comment: (20) * (20, 3, 3, 1) = (20, 3, 3, 1)

Comment: `random_part[:,None, None, None]*img_placeholder`

Answer (score 2):

TensorFlow uses same broadcasting rules as numpy, so in your example shape (20) first gets extended *on the left* with singleton dimensions to become (1, 1, 1, 20), and then singleton dimensions are matched one both sides to have shape (20, 3, 3, 20).

If you want (20) to be treated as a batch dimension, you should reshape it to have the same rank

```
>>> a=np.ones((5,))
>>> b=np.ones((5,28,28,1))
>>> (a*b).shape
(5, 28, 28, 5)
>>> b.shape
(5, 28, 28, 1)
>>> a.shape
(5,)
>>> a2 = np.reshape(a, [len(a), 1, 1, 1])
>>> a2.shape
(5, 1, 1, 1)
>>> (a2*b).shape
(5, 28, 28, 1)
```

Comment: I've checked after posting the question that my idea didn't work even in NumPy and I reshaped it. Thanks!